# C# ASP.net - How to use Json object auto mapping in models

Tags: c#, asp.net

How I can create models to auto map this json object response in Class with root models.

I create the models with json convert to c#  it's return null values

This is my json object response.

```
{
"factivityactual": [],
"fkpi": [
    {
        "note_id": "1DAE3D4A74A7DE91472588D20024C114",
        "sql_id": "test",
        "RefKPI_Detail": "test",
        "Refdocid": "144149A40134720B472588D20024C110",
        "criterion_1": "test",
        "criterion_2": "test",
        "criterion_3": "test",
        "criterion_Type": "2",
        "criterion_4": "test",
        "criterion_5": "test"
    }
],
"factivityplan": [
    {
        "Q2_sum_Comment": "",
        "sql_id": "",
        "Q1_sum_Comment": "",
        "Activity": "TEST",
        "Q2_sum_Budget": "",
        "Month": "01",
        "Q4_sum_Comment": "",
        "Q3_sum_Comment": "",
        "Order": 0,
        "M_Budget1": 0,
        "M_Budget2": 0,
        "TypeActivity": "test",
        "M_Budget3": 0,
        "M_Budget4": 0,
        "M_Budget5": 0,
        "M_Budget6": 0,
        "Q4_sum_Budget": "",
        "Unit_T": "test",
        "M_Budget10": 0,
        "M_Budget11": 0,
        "OwnerProject": "à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š~à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š~à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š",
        "M_Budget12": 0,
        "Q3_sum_Budget": "",
        "Detail": "",
        "MainNameActivity": "test",
        "M_Comment10": "test",
        "M_Comment11": "test",
        "M_Comment12": "test",
        "Q1_sum_Budget": "",
        "DetailOwnerName": "à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š~à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š~à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š",
        "RefDocID": "144149A40134720B472588D20024C110",
        "M_Budget7": 0,
        "M_Budget8": 0,
        "Budget": 0,
        "FaceName": "test",
        "M_Budget9": 0,
        "Budget2": 0,
        "note_id": "B6783436311E7280472588D20024C115",
        "M_Comment9": "test",
        "sumDetailP": "test",
        "M_Comment7": "test",
        "M_Comment8": "test",
        "M_Comment5": "test",
        "M_Comment6": "test",
        "M_Comment3": "test",
        "M_Comment4": "test",
        "NameActivity": "test",
        "M_Comment1": "test",
        "M_Comment2": "test",
        "criterion_Type": "2"
    }
],
"fproject": {
    "note_id": "144149A40134720B472588D20024C110",
    "CurrentOwner": "à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š~à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š~à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š",
    "sql_id": "test",
    "FormTitle": "test",
    "ProjectName": ".net",
    "StatusText": "test",
    "StatusNo": "100",
    "IDFac": "test",
    "OwnerNamelist": "test",
    "SYear": "test",
    "Reason": "test",
    "Result": "TEST",
    "EPeriod": "",
    "budgetyear": "",
    "Goal": "test",
    "ProjectStatus": "1",
    "ApproveOwner": "à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š~à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š~à¸—à¸”à¸ªà¸­à¸š",
    "budget2": 0,
    "SPeriod": "",
    "FaceName": "test",
    "Updatedate_dt": "",
    "ProjectDetail": "test",
    "budget": 0,
    "budgetApprove": 0
}
}
```

And this is my controller code

```
    public static Root LoadDetailDataAPI()
    {
        Root ListData = new Root();

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.mywebsite.com/Develop/Project/Niems/EmitPlan.nsf/project.xsp/getprojectfull");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json;  charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))//, Encoding.UTF8
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                note_id = "144149A40134720B472588D20024C110"
            });

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            ListData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);
        }

        
        return ListData;
    }
```

`Factivityplan` is returned as `null`. `Fkpi` and `Fproject` just binding `note_id` and `sql_id`. I do not have other fields. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already trying to map model to model using property names that match each other I would suggest looking into [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/), that way you can simply map them directly without too much hassle like so:

```
mapper.Map<WantedDestinationType>(sourceModel);
```

If nothing else is configured, it'll simply map the types using the names only, if you have different naming, you can set it up in your mapping profile etc.